# knit does not work even though the code works

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I made a .Rmd file and I'm trying to knit to HTML.
But there's an error showing, even though the code works.

I pressed the knit to HTML button. The YAML is fine as well.
The error is:

```
Error in `.External2()`:
! unable to start data viewer
Backtrace:
 1. utils::View(components)
Execution halted
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-start-data-viewer/142321)

Using `View()` is going to throw errors when knitting.

Try just using `print(your_object)` where `View(your_object)`

Comment: It worked. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Great - please mark the answer as correct if it worked. That way other users can clearly see what solution worked for future reference